# AWS Boto3 method "update_auto_scaling_group()" intermittent silent fail

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3

I'm trying to update my Auto Scaling Group **"DesiredCapacity"** using python Boto3 command named **"update_auto_scaling_group"**. Generally it works fine but sometimes this command silently fails and doesn't update anything, the response of this method does not give me any clue on what is happening since it's "http Code 200-OK". I'm also making sure that the MaxSize of the auto scaling group is greater than the desired.

```
response = client.update_auto_scaling_group(
    AutoScalingGroupName="AutoScalingGroupName",
    DesiredCapacity=2, 
    MaxSize=3
)
```

Request response.

```
{
'RequestId': '70e5673c-aaad-11t9-9edd-12345678aee1', 
'HTTPStatusCode': 200, 
'HTTPHeaders': {'x-amzn-requestid': '70e5673c-aaad-11t9-9edd-12345678aee1', 'content-type': 'text/xml', 'content-length': '231', 'date': 'Tue, 05 Nov 2019 18:52:39 GMT'}, 
'RetryAttempts': 0
}
```

I read all the documentation regarding the possible fails on this method, but it says that in all cases of error the response http code is different from 200.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/pt_br/autoscaling/ec2/APIReference/API_UpdateAutoScalingGroup.html

I also have a function to check if the value of the desired capacity has changed correctly and it always falsely responds that it was updated. When I check the Desired capacity on AWS console I see that it hasn't change.

```
def is_autoscaling_updated(desired: int, configs: ConfigParameters):
  client = boto3.client(
    'autoscaling',
    aws_access_key_id="myAccessKeyId",
    aws_secret_access_key="mySecretAccessKey",
    region_name="myRegion"
  )

  response = client.describe_auto_scaling_groups(
      AutoScalingGroupNames=["MyAutoScalingGroupName"]
  )

  desired_response = response['AutoScalingGroups'][0]['DesiredCapacity']

  if desired_response != desired:
     return False

  return True
```

Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: Could you please edit your question to show the code of the `update_auto_scaling_group()` function? Have you been sending some debug information to a log to track the values sent to AWS, so you can check it when a request does not work as expected? Have you considered adding some code before & after the API call to retrieve the current value of `DesiredCapacity` to confirm that the value is not changing? (Bottom line: Log everything!)

Comment: Hi John, the update_auto_scaling_group() function belongs to Boto3, a Python framework for AWS usage, here is the documentation. https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/autoscaling.html#AutoScaling.Client.update_auto_scaling_group

Yes, I have a debug log that shows me that the desired capacity is correctly set before que function call.

I also have a code to check if the auto scaling has been modified, I will edit the question to include it.

Comment: **Side-note:** You should not put credentials in your code. Instead, if you are running the code on an Amazon EC2 instance, simply assign an IAM Role to the instance. If you are not running the code on EC2, then use a credentials file to store the credentials. An easy way to do this is to use the AWS CLI `aws configure` command.

Comment: Do you have more than one Auto Scaling group with the same name? Because `response['AutoScalingGroups'][0]['DesiredCapacity']` assumes that the first one returned is the desired one.

Comment: Thanks for the Side-note John, we will use the roles in EC2 production.

Comment: About the Auto Scaling Group name, we double check it and this is a single name in our environment. We also made a hole new ASG with a test name and we had the same problem, it generally works but eventually it fails with no feedback of errors in the function response. =(

Comment: Is it possible the command was actually succeeding, but then some other process was undoing your change? I found myself here while investigating a similar issue, and that turned out to be the cause.